# Why is my second digit the same as my third digit value?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

May I ask about what mistake had I made that cause me 2nd digit value(R2) become always same as 3rd digit value(R1)?

**For example:**
I had done is Total Price : 88,
Amount Given : 100,
so the final answer consist of 3 digit should be 012, but it appear with 022

**For example:**
2 is Total price 99,
Amount given :100,
final answer should be 001, but it come out with 011

Below line is the function that I used to do the calculation.

```
GIVECHANGE:

MOV AH,09H
LEA DX,STRCHANGEGIVEN
INT 21H

MOV AL,TTL  ;--move total price into AL TTL=88
SUB TTG,AL  ;--use total given - AL TTG = 100
MOV BL,TTG  ;-- BL = 100-88 = 12

MOV TTC,BL  ;--store result to TTC = 12

MOV AX,0
MOV AL,TTC
DIV TEN

MOV Q1,AL
MOV R1,AH
MOV AX,0
MOV AL,R1
DIV TEN

MOV Q2,AL
MOV R2,AH

ADD Q2,30H
ADD R2,30H
ADD R1,30H

MOV AH,02H
MOV DL,Q2
INT 21H

MOV AH,02H
MOV DL,R2
INT 21H
    
MOV AH,02H
MOV DL,R1
INT 21H
```

Comment: I would step through the code in a debugger and check what happens to your registers and variables at every step and see where the code's behavior differs from my expectations.

Comment: `MOV AL,R1` should be `MOV AL,Q1`.

Comment: W.Chang thank you, the way you provide solved my problem :D

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit difficult to answer your question without running it, but what i can suggest to you for this problem or other problems is to use a debugger and see your variables, memory, flags, registers... states , the one i use is **emu8086** it is a user-friendly one, it has a very good debugger, as you can see(picture below) it has a lot of options, it will save you a lot of time instead of searching for bugs, you can detect them by yourself.
[Image about emu8086 debugger interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbaJm.png)